# MacBook Pro Keyboard Backlight Error Icon?

Tags: macbook-pro, keyboard, error

When I use the Keyboard Backlight buttons (F5 and F6) I get this error icon?

https://ibb.co/bwod2T

Comment: Your question is missing a bunch of info.  What OS?  When did this start?  What have you already tried to fix the problem?  Have you searched this site for similar questions and tried the answers already provided?  Please [edit] your question to include this info.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears this warning icon means that it's too light to turn on the Keyboard Backlight. Very misleading icon suggests an error.

---

You can test this by holding a flashlight up to the light sensor.

Comment: Source........?

Comment: Source: I did it.

Comment: Did what......?

Comment: Put finger over light sensor obviously ...

Comment: Just confirmed. You are correct.

Comment: It's the correct answer. Whether it is -1, -250 or +400 makes no difference to my ego.

Comment: I did it for you :)

Answer (score 0):

Try resetting the SMC.

From [here](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201295):

> ### How to reset the System Management Controller (SMC) on your Mac *Learn when and how to reset the SMC on an Intel-based Mac.*
>
> **What the SMC does**
>
> The SMC is responsible for these and other low-level functions on
>   Intel-based Mac computers:
>
> ...
>
> - Keyboard backlighting
>
> ...
>
> ### How to know if you need to reset the SMC
>
> These symptoms might mean that an SMC reset is necessary:
>
> ....
>
> - The keyboard backlight behaves incorrectly.
> - The display backlight doesn't respond correctly to ambient light
>
> ....
>
> ### How to reset the SMC on Mac notebooks
>
> First, determine whether the battery is removable. Most older Mac
>   notebooks have removable batteries. Mac notebooks that have
>   nonremovable batteries include MacBook Pro (Early 2009 and later), all
>   models of MacBook Air, MacBook (Late 2009), and MacBook (Retina,
>   12-inch, Early 2015 and later). Learn more about Mac notebook
>   batteries.
>
> **If the battery is nonremovable:**
>
> 1. Choose Apple menu > Shut Down.
> 2. After your Mac shuts down, press Shift-Control-Option on the left side of the built-in keyboard, then press the power button at the same
>      time. Hold these keys and the power button for 10 seconds.
>
>    *If you have a MacBook Pro with Touch ID, the Touch ID button is also
>      the power button.*
> 3. Release all keys.
> 4. Press the power button again to turn on your Mac.
>
> ---
>
> **If the battery is removable:**
>
> 1. Shut down your Mac.
> 2. Remove the battery. If you need help removing the battery, contact an Apple Authorized Service Provider or Apple Retail Store.
> 3. Press and hold the power button for 5 seconds.
> 4. Reinstall the battery.
> 5. Press the power button again to turn on your Mac.
>
> ### How to reset the SMC on Mac desktop computers
>
> Follow these steps for iMac, Mac mini, Mac Pro, and Xserve. If you
>   have an iMac Pro, skip to the next section.
>
> 1. Choose Apple menu > Shut Down.
> 2. After your Mac shuts down, unplug the power cord.
> 3. Wait 15 seconds.
> 4. Plug the power cord back in.
> 5. Wait 5 seconds, then press the power button again to turn on your Mac.
> 6. For Intel-based Xserve computers that aren't responding, you can shut down locally or by using remote commands. You can also press and
>      hold the power button for 5 seconds.
>
> ### How to reset the SMC on iMac Pro
>
> 1. Follow these steps for iMac Pro:
> 2. Choose Apple menu > Shut Down.
> 3. After your iMac Pro shuts down, press and hold its power button for 8 seconds.
> 4. Release the power button, then wait a few seconds.
> 5. Press the power button again to turn on your iMac Pro.